# Code that prints out a right triangle. Each line has numbers and that at the end of each line is the sum of all numbers in it

Tags: python

What I have so far:

```
n=10

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print(j,end=' ')
    print('')
```

That prints out:

```
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The output should be:

```
0 1 1
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 6
0 1 2 3 4 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 15
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 21
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 28
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 36
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 45
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 55
```

At the end of each line is the sum of all the numbers in the line. For example, in line 5, the sum of all numbers in that line is 15.

As you can see I am missing the sum of all the numbers at the end of each line. Should I add another for-loop? Should I change the inner loop? I don't know what code I should use to get the sum of the numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: Check out what `sum(range(0, j+1))` does

Comment: btw: `range(j+n==n)` doesn't seem right.

Comment: You can track your own sum, if you want to.  Set `sumx = 0` before the `for j` loop.  Put `sumx += j` inside the `for j` loop.  `print(sumx)` after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can track your own sum, if you want to.

```
n=10

for i in range(1,n+1):
    sumx = 0
    for j in range(i+1):
        sumx += j
        print(j,end=' ')
    print(sumx)
```

Or, microscopically better:

```
n=10
sumx = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(i+1):
        print(j,end=' ')
    sumx += i
    print(sumx)
```

Comment: Would be more efficient to sum the `i` values (not that it matters, since printing the lines will dominate the time anyway).

Comment: So, you're suggesting doing a cumulative sum, just adding the new element on each line?  It's a microscopic optimization, completely swamped by the I/O as you mentioned, but it's completely in character for SO and thus is worth modifying my answer to propose that as well.

Comment: Yeah, like that. Except I added *before* the inner loop. Since you do it *after*, you could even keep it as `+= j` instead, somewhat emphasizing that you're adding the last number in the row (which will still be in `j` after the loop). But I think yours is better.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest way:

```
n=10

for i in range(1,n+1):
    r = range(i+1)
    print(*r, sum(r))
```